# How to "Preview" a request in the Apache Wink Client

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, apache-wink

Using the Apache Wink Client, is there a standard way to see what Request would be sent from an invoke() operation?  I can build it from the Resource object, but I was wondering if there is a utility or standard way for achieving this, to see a request in a way similar to how the browsers' network tab displays it?

ie..

```
PUT /my/api HTTP/1.1
Host: my.host.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 29
Authorization: Basic --!---
Origin: https://my.host.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Referer: https://my.host.example.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: JSESSIONID=--!---
Request Payload
{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find such method of Wink to preview the HTTP request in raw view. You could use **HTTP tool** to monitor the raw data.

Moreover, Wink framework is implementation JAX-RS, which is an abstract for RESTful concept. So it's not proper layer to check the raw HTTP data.